# Powershell compare two files and generate third file

Tags: file, powershell, text, compare

I have 2 files - file1.txt and file2.txt. I want to compare these two files with powershell and generate third file (file3.txt) which containst all the lines from file1.txt minus lines in file2.txt

Here is an example of how the files 1 and 2 looks like:

file1.txt content

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

file2.txt content

```
Line2
Line4
```

And I want file3.txt to look like this

```
Line1
Line3
```

Can you think of some way how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is ridiculously easy...

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content File1.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content File2.txt) -PassThru | Out-File File3.txt
```

That's all there is to it.