# PowerShell script to compare two files and merge the output the into a third file

Tags: powershell, compare

I have have 2 files which I need to compare with PowerShell and generate the 3rd file with the merge output which contains all the lines from `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

This is an example of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`:

file1.txt content

```
"Name","RcopyGroup","State","Type","Prov","UsrCPG","VSize_MB","Usr_Rsvd_MB","Usr_Used_Perc","Usr_Used_MB","Snp_Rsvd_MB","Snp_Used_Perc"
".srdata","-","normal","base","full","-","81920","81920","100.0","81920","0","0.0"
"admin","-","normal","base","full","-","12288","12288","100.0","12288","0","0.0"
"LUN1","-","normal","base","tpvv","SSD_CPG","1331200","1159552","85.6","1139240","17408","0.0"
"LUN2","-","normal","base","tpvv","FC_CPG","122880","82944","52.3","64304","17408","0.0"
"LUN3","-","normal","base","tpvv","SSD_CPG","71680","56320","73.7","52861","1024","0.0"
"LUN4","-","normal","base","tpvv","FC_CPG","40960","33792","77.9","31922","1024","0.0"
"LUN5","-","normal","base","tpvv","FC_CPG","10240","11264","99.7","10209","1024","0.0"
```

File2.txt Content

```
"Name","LunID","PresentTo","vvWWN"
"LUN1","10","Host1","60002AC0000000000000004400015537"
"LUN1","10","Host3","60002AC0000000000000004400015537"
"LUN1","110","Host2","60002AC0000000000000004400015537"
"LUN1","209","Host5","60002AC0000000000000004400015537"
"LUN1","110","Host4","60002AC0000000000000004400015537"
"LUN2","111","Host2","60002AC000000000080019FC000153AF"
"LUN3","110","Host2","60002AC000000000080019FD000153AF"
"LUN4","210","Host2","60002AC0000000000A004BC500015537"
"LUN5","211","Host2","60002AC0000000000A004BC700015537"
"LUN4","210","Host5","60002AC0000000000A004BC500015537"
"LUN5","211","Host5","60002AC0000000000A004BC700015537"
```

and i want the output on file3.txt to be like this

```
"Name","RcopyGroup","State","Type","Prov","UsrCPG","VSize_MB","Usr_Rsvd_MB","Usr_Used_Perc","Usr_Used_MB","Snp_Rsvd_MB","Snp_Used_Perc","PresentTo"
".srdata","-","normal","base","full","-","81920","81920","100.0","81920","0","0.0",""
"admin","-","normal","base","full","-","12288","12288","100.0","12288","0","0.0",""
"LUN1","-","normal","base","tpvv","SSD_CPG","1331200","1159552","85.6","1139240","17408","0.0","Host1;Host3;Host2;Host5;Host4"
"LUN2","-","normal","base","tpvv","FC_CPG","122880","82944","52.3","64304","17408","0.0","Host2"
"LUN3","-","normal","base","tpvv","SSD_CPG","71680","56320","73.7","52861","1024","0.0","Host2"
"LUN4","-","normal","base","tpvv","FC_CPG","40960","33792","77.9","31922","1024","0.0","Host2;Host5"
"LUN5","-","normal","base","tpvv","FC_CPG","10240","11264","99.7","10209","1024","0.0","Host2;Host5"
```

I have check the similar post in the forum [Powershell compare two files and generate third file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954786/powershell-compare-two-files-and-generate-third-file)
but it is not producing the result which i required. Can someone help to think of a way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your code attempt, and where you believe it may be failing at?

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)):
 `$file1 |Join $file2 -On Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Group-Object` cmdlet to work out the hosts for each name and then add a new property to each of the new objects from file1 with the grouped data joined using `-join ";"`.

```
$file1 = Import-Csv .\file1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv .\file2.csv

# Group file2 by Name and output as a hashtable 
$group2 = $file2 | Select-Object Name, PresentTo | Group-Object -Property Name -AsHashTable

$file1 | ForEach-Object {
    # Add the new property (column) 'PresentTo' with the matching file2 Hosts joined by ';'
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PresentTo -NotePropertyValue ($group2.($_.Name).PresentTo -join ';') -PassThru
} | Export-Csv .\file3.csv

# have a look at our new file
Import-Csv .\file3.csv | Format-Table *
```

Output

```
Name    RcopyGroup State  Type Prov UsrCPG  VSize_MB Usr_Rsvd_MB Usr_Used_Perc Usr_Used_MB Snp_Rsvd_MB Snp_Used_Perc PresentTo
----    ---------- -----  ---- ---- ------  -------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ---------
.srdata -          normal base full -       81920    81920       100.0         81920       0           0.0
admin   -          normal base full -       12288    12288       100.0         12288       0           0.0
LUN1    -          normal base tpvv SSD_CPG 1331200  1159552     85.6          1139240     17408       0.0           Host1;Host3;Host2;Host5;Host4
LUN2    -          normal base tpvv FC_CPG  122880   82944       52.3          64304       17408       0.0           Host2
LUN3    -          normal base tpvv SSD_CPG 71680    56320       73.7          52861       1024        0.0           Host2
LUN4    -          normal base tpvv FC_CPG  40960    33792       77.9          31922       1024        0.0           Host2;Host5
LUN5    -          normal base tpvv FC_CPG  10240    11264       99.7          10209       1024        0.0           Host2;Host5
```